# Inserting dashes into string

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to know how I could insert dashed into various points into a string?
I have a string that is 32 characters long
I need dashes in various places
8-4-4-4-12

8 characters - 4characters... and so on till string is complete.

I tried REGEX but can only get it to add dashes at regular intervals

```
 string newString = Regex.Replace(currentEPC, ".{6}", "$0-");
```

I am trying to parse a string as a Guid, but my string does not contain dashes, which it needs to be converted to the Guid.

Comment: What makes you think you need dashes to be able to parse a GUID? You can easily do `Guid.Parse("36b1dbc650c6407098247f87790144ff")` for example.

Comment: @DavidG beat me by 1 second haha

Comment: well, obviously i need the dashes, because I am doing it wrong :) Thanks to both of you for the help

Comment: If you want to insert characters into a string you can use:  StringVariable.Insert(8, "-");  where 8 is the location in the string, but as others are saying for GUILDs there are better ways then doing this manually

Comment: `string newString = Regex.Replace(oldString, "(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})", "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to parse a string as a Guid, but my string does not contain dashes, which it needs to be converted to the Guid.

No, it doesn't:

```
Guid g = Guid.Parse("084c1bfd133d403384e1c02113b52f8c");
```

This will parse the GUID for you. If you want to have it in a string representation with dashes:

```
string s = g.ToString();
```

Comment: To OP, you can see the proof in action [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D0v92W) @PatrickHofman, feel free to include the fiddle in your answer if you would like

Comment: Documentation of `Guid.ToString()` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RandRandom And your question is?

Answer (score 2):

As Patrick has shown, you don't need to insert the dashes to parse the string to `Guid`.

However, if you need this method anyway you can use:

```
public static string InsertStrings(string text, string insertString, params int[] rangeLengths)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(text);
    var indexes = new int[rangeLengths.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
        indexes[i] = rangeLengths[i] + indexes.ElementAtOrDefault(i-1) + insertString.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
    {
        if(indexes[i] < sb.Length)
            sb.Insert(indexes[i], insertString);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Usage:

```
string guidString = "36b1dbc650c6407098247f87790144ff";
guidString =  InsertStrings(guidString, "-", 8, 4, 4, 4, 12);
```